# How to use a predicate to filter the multiple POJOs which do not inherit the same interface

Tags: java

What if I had the following POJOs - Library, Book, Author. And at some point, I would want to make a query the Library for all Books and Authors that match the specified name or other keyword and return those which are matched. But the problem is that Book and Author do not inherit the same interface to use in the predicate. Could you please explain how to make it work in this case?

Comment: why don't you try with InstanceOf keyword? @user

Answer (score 0):

How about a library app? The `Library` (a class) stores the books (`Book` class) as `List<Book>` collection. A `Book` has attributes (or properties) `title` and `author` (`Author` class has a `name` attribute).

For searching the books in the library one can define multiple predicates (of type `java.util.function.Predicate`); e.g., a predicate to search books in the library by `title` can be something like:

```
Predicate<Book> titleMatch = book -> book.getTitle().contains(searchBookTitle);
```

Where `searchBookTitle` is the provided search string.

So, filter the `books` collection of the library, by search criteria applying the predicate (search by title, as in example predicate above) and print the matching books.

```
books.stream()
     .filter(titleMatch)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

More predicates may be defined (and applied as needed), and here are some:

```
Predicate<Book> authorMatch = b -> b.getAuthor().getName().contains(inAuthorName);
Predicate<Book> bookAndAuthorMatch = bookMatch.and(authorMatch);
Predicate<Book> bookOrAutherMatch = bookMatch.or(authorMatch);
```